# mysql large number of rows query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query:

```
EXPLAIN
  SELECT
     id,
     name,
     title,
     description,
     time
  FROM entity
  WHERE 
    (date_end > CURRENT_DATE 
       OR (date_end = CURRENT_DATE AND time_end >= CURRENT_TIME)
     )
     AND (next_date < CURRENT_DATE 
        OR (next_date = CURRENT_DATE AND next_time <= CURRENT_TIME)
     )
```

When can I do to make this query take less time when handling 10000+ rows in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing/Analyzing explain plan will help more to answer.

although I guess adding composite index on `[date_end, time_end]` and  `[next_date,next_time]` might help

Answer (score 0):

If possible, combine the date_end and time_end columns into a single datetime_end column, similarly for the next_date and next_time column as next_datetime, and set up an index on datetime_end, next_datetime. You can then rewrite your query as:

```
  SELECT id, name, title, description, time
  FROM entity
  WHERE datetime_end >= now() and next_datetime <= now()
```

Comment: I don't think that will work.. it appears his table has date in one field, time in another, and if not a true date/time field for time_end, he's a bit stuck on what he already has.

Comment: I was advising him to change his database design - if possible.

Comment: DOOhhhh...  brain cramp this morning... didn't even read your comments about it..  Can someone say caffeine